# How to modify Dictionary object in method in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm new to Swift. I'm having dictionary and i'm passing it to some method which should be able to modify it. What's the best solution for it, return new Dictionary (seems to be inefficient because of copying needed):

```
func method(let dict : [String:String]) -> [String:String] {
    var newDictionary = [String:String]()
    ... // copy to newDictionary/remove existing items 
}
```

or pass it as `inout` argument (is it working?):

```
func method(inout dict : [String:String]) {
    ... // modify existing dictionary
}
```

Comment: Passing it as inout is like passing a pointer is Cpp if I'm not misleaded. But yhea it should work, I use inout this way in my code and it's working great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An in-out parameter has a value that is passed in to the function, is modified by the function, and is passed back out of the function to replace the original value.

As said here, it will modify the instance that is passed as inout parameter. So in your case it's definitively what you want to do, in my opinion.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html ctrl+f "inout"

Comment: BTW, is there any more efficient way to pass dictionary by reference in order to let a method modify it? According to `inout` docs there are 2 copies here: when local is create out of passed variable and back.

Comment: Not that I am aware of, but I think it's unlikely.
More insight can be found here, for understanding how it works behind the scene: (ctrl+f "inout") https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID545